# Как удалить файлы с замком и очистить флешку?

Tags: linux

Используя советы в инернете, и пытаясь установить новый дистрибутив, пришлось сделать запись на флешку через распаковку iso-образа.

Опять же, не получилось загрузиться. Решил перезаписать через интерфейс, предварительно очистив флешку.

**И тут как раз и возникла проблема так как файловый менеджер и програмки не могут удалить содержимое,возможно потому что сами папки весят под замком и требуют *root*.**

Как решить данную проблему?

Дистрибутив - `Xubuntu`. Ставил - `Linux Mint LXDE` (поправьте)

Comment: а в чем проблема открыть консоль и от рута почистить все?

Comment: @KoVadim В том то и проблема,что еще только разбираюсь.А команды,которые люди в интернете предлагают либо не рабочие либо немного опасные

Comment: логично, что опасные

Comment: я дополнил свой ответ по поводу записи образа на блочное устройство.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы записали (не «распаковали», а именно записали) iso-образ («обычный» установочный) на блочное устройство, то у вас сейчас на блочном устройстве один раздел с файловой системой iso9660 (или аналогичной), которая является «файловой системой только для чтения».

поэтому вам надо удалить все разделы с блочного устройства и создать заново один (или больше, если требуется) раздел, который уже форматировать под какую-нибудь файловую систему.

если обмена файлами с *ms/windows* не предполагается, можно выбрать файловую систему ext2/ext3/ext4. если предполагается, лучше, вероятно, выбрать *fat* или даже *ntfs*.

всё это можно сделать, например, с помощью упомянутой вами gui-программы *gparted*.

---

но, судя по тому, что вы хотите опять записать установочный iso-образ, никаких манипуляций с разделами не требуется. вам необходимо (исходим из того, что блочное устройство — `/dev/sdb`):

1. отмонтировать все примонтированные с блочного устройства разделы:

   ```
   $ sudo umount /dev/sdb*
   ```
2. записать образ на устройство:

   ```
   $ sudo cp /путь/к/образу /dev/sdb
   ```

Comment: А зачем нужно удаление и повторное создание раздела? Чтобы проблем с его размером не было? Или форматирование тут не получится по какой-то причине?

Comment: @alexander barakin Спасибо!Исходя из ваших советов,немного еще потанцевал с бубном и все получилось.Правда с помощью GUI. `GPARTED+UnetBootin`

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что и рассказывать про изменение типа раздела дольше, и удалить/создать ничуть не сложнее/дольше, чем менять тип.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ещё: если на бл.устройство был записан образ, то размер раздела явно меньше размера бл. устройства. т.е., если *без удаления*, то ещё и про изменение размера раздела надо бы рассказать. потому проще посоветовать: удалите/создайте.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно удалить с флешки всё, то предлагаю её просто отформатировать.

Comment: Использовал GParted.Вроде отформатировал,показывает интерфейс -чистая,но папки остались на флешке...(смотрел через файловый менеджер)

Comment: @Maksym, в минте есть уже установленное приложение. Поиск по слову `disk` в стартовом меню.

Answer (score 1):

В Ubuntu есть специальная программа записи загрузочных дисков, она сама умеет "очищать" подобные флешки (есть кнопочка "Erase Disk/Форматировать"). См. [How to create a bootable USB stick
on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)